# Is it possible to disinguish between server and client in babelrc config (meteor)?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, babeljs

Iam using meteor and want to have a babel plugin only for server side code activated. Is it possible to do it via babelrc config or directly in babel plugin? Something like

`if(isServer) { //Do your thing only for server sided code}`

--Edit:

For better description, i have the following example:

```
import HelloWorld from "/imports/components/HelloWorld";

export const ROUTES = [
    {
        label: "Test",
        path: "/TEST",
        role: ["test.view"],
        component: HelloWorld, //Render für Route
    },
]
```

Now i want to use this code on both side (server and client). On server side i can't use this import, because it leads to some errors. For me it would be best to simply filter the import line and component line in routes. Therefore i want to distinguish between server and client in a babel plugin.

Comment: I assume you already know about `Meteor.isServer`. Can you elaborate why you specifically need a way for babel to handle this?

Comment: Meteor.isServer is not available in a babel plugin. I want to filter some Imports with a code blocke which i only need on clientside, but not on server side. Therefore i need this distinction in my babel plugin or in the config.

Comment: With proper imports structure, it should be easy to separate client-only and server-only code in most cases. In the cases where it is harder, it does not harm having client-only code bundled with server app, provided that you guard it with `Meteor.isClient`. For the reverse (prevent server-only code from being shipped to client), you can use dynamic import and place the import in a `server` folder. Then all cases are covered, no need to fiddle with Babel.

Comment: @ghybs I added a code example. If iam using dynamic imports, i would get a reference Error in code line 8 (component: HelloWorld)

Comment: What was your code when you tried dynamic import? What does your server do (or does not do) when it imports this `ROUTES`, since you import it on both sides, but need `HelloWorld` only on client side?

Comment: HelloWorld is a react component, which can be rendered only on client side. I want to define my routes only one time together with some permission to call these routes. For this use case i need the other route information (like path, role) on server side.
On client side array routes is used to fill configuration for react-router-dom .

Comment: Given your description, dynamic import is definitely the way to go, with even the added benefit of client side lazy loading, provided that your server code does not need to access the `component` key.

Comment: @ghybs you are right. Thanks for your input, rebuild my use case with dynamic imports.

Answer (score 0):

In babelrc it is not directly possible, but it possible to make the destinction in a babel plugin.

Option Caller in Babel 7 is what i was looking for.

Small code example from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52315868/8188913

```
let caller;
module.exports = function(Babel) {
    Babel.caller(function(c) {
            caller = { ...c };
    });
    return {
        visitor: {
            BlockStatement(){
                console.log(caller); // logs e.g. {name: "meteor", arch: "web.browser.legacy"}
            }
        }
    };
};
```

With source code from babel plugin [babel-plugin-transform-strip-block](https://github.com/felix-kaestner/babel-plugin-transform-strip-block) i was able to build a complete solution for my use case.

Anyway this is not the best way to solve this use case. So after some input from ghybs (see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70410238/is-it-possible-to-disinguish-between-server-and-client-in-babelrc-config-meteor#comment124487800_70410238)), dynamic imports is the best way to go here.

Comment: If your question is solved by another post, you should close it as a duplicate of the previous one